# 2-SAT reduction to Easy Puzzle Solving

Tags: complexity-theory, sudoku

### Introduction

I've been developing interest in complexity classes and thought I was unable to prove my problem is *NP hard*, so I wanted to see if it was *P-hard*. I wanted to see if my puzzle solving is special.  *I have linked a previous question of mine to help clarify what is mentioned below.*  [Explained here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109213/np-hardness-of-unique-puzzle-generation)

### Random Instance of 2-SAT used for attempt reduction

> I took an instance of my problem X
>
> *Let's say my problem X is determining if a puzzle is valid for my language*
>
> (a∨¬b)∧(¬a∨b)∧(¬a∨¬b)∧(a∨¬c)
>
> *Instance of X*
>
> a = shift(L) puzzle
>
> ¬ a = invalid puzzle
>
> ¬b =  invalid puzzle
>
> b = shift(L) puzzle

---

### Reduction into Shorter Instance

> (a∨¬b)∧(¬a∨b)

*This boolean expression is only checking for 2-sat. Being True  (valid puzzle) or False (invalid puzzle).*

My idea is that a deterministic machine will consider *n^2 x n^2* puzzles as invalid if the lower right-hand box is not filled. My puzzles are solved in quadratic time when provided a puzzle with this *n x n* box. Any other puzzle will simply fail to be solved if it does not follow my language. *I have used an algorithm that can determine in poly-time that those failed puzzles are invalid puzzles.* Because, the solver will not know it as an invalid puzzle. So it will try to map it out in my language thus giving an invalid puzzle.

### Question

I have the algorithm and proven that it works in poly-time, the problem is that *I only know how to prove it by showing the algorithm*. I just don't know how to write it out mathematically. How would I properly do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to need to question your premise here.

I have no doubt that you can poly-time reduce `2SAT` to your custom problem. But you can poly-time reduce `2SAT` to pretty much *anything*. The idea of "P-hardness" under poly-time reduction isn't really a useful one.

For example, let's take the following problem:

> `IS-IT-ONE`: given a single bit, is that bit a 1?

This problem is "P-hard" under poly-time reduction. For example, I can reduce `2SAT` to it:

> **Reduction from `2SAT` to `IS-IT-ONE`**
>
> - Solve `2SAT` the usual way
> - If the problem is satisfiable, let $B$ be 1
> - If the problem is unsatisfiable, let $B$ be 0
> - Run `IS-IT-ONE` on $B$ and return the result

This reduction runs in poly-time, *because solving `2SAT` can be done in poly-time*.

In other words:

***Every problem in P can be poly-time reduced to any other non-trivial problem.***

(Only two languages are considered "trivial" for this purpose: "return true" and "return false", aka $\Sigma^*$ and $\varnothing$.)

If you're interested in classes smaller than P, great! There are several of them, such as L: the set of problems that can be solved using a logarithmic amount of memory. It may or may not be the same as P—that's an open problem.

But if you want to talk about P versus L or NL or anything else within P, you can't use poly-time reductions any more. When talking about L, for example, you'll usually want a *log-space reduction*, using a Turing machine with writable tape bounded by the log of the input size. These aren't as famous as poly-time reductions, but they're still quite important in complexity theory.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look into log space for a few days and try and see what I can get. I share this in form of question on CS. Preferably, on meta first.

Comment: @TravisWells I'd suggest taking some time away from your simplified-sudoku generator for a bit, too. Read up on complexity theory, and try some NP-hardness proofs for other problems. Then focus on log-space, and try some log-space reductions for other problems too, focusing on the difference between P and L. *Then* come back to your sudoku generator.

Comment: I agree that I need to take a break,  I've already starting to understand how to reduce SAT into a 3-SAT Instance. I've managed to follow restricted reductions.   3-SAT to vertex cover is probably easier to understand. Given time, may we take this to chat so that I can learn this quickly as possible? I have a link to this. http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/ko/pdfs/lecture-21.pdf

Comment: @TravisWells pick a book, if you want to learn as quickly as possible, throw away your shifter-mapper, please.

Comment: @Evil  Figuring out how many solutions my n^2 x n^2 puzzles have seems to be #P complete. I'm going to search up a e-book. Throwing away the project would be foolish. Postponing it and studying reductions is what I'm doing.

Comment: @TravisWells I agree with Evil, honestly. Your fixation on this shifter-mapper-thing is holding you back, especially since you can't even state what the problem is in a succinct way: your explanation is scattered across four different web pages now and involves sentences like "let shift by shift be defined by the formula x by y" which I can't make heads or tails of. I can tell you right now that your new question almost certainly isn't #P-complete, since #P is defined in terms of NP, and I'm confident your problem isn't NP-complete (though I don't understand it well enough to prove anything).

Comment: My advice is, take a class on complexity theory, watch some lectures, read a textbook, and then some articles. But **don't** try to apply everything you learn to this shifter-mapper-thing. It's just not a solid enough framework for you to try to force all of complexity theory into, and it'll just impede your learning.

Comment: @Draconis Then postponing it is. Just going to keep reading books. Until, then I'll see if my intuition was right or wrong. Especially with counting how many solutions n^2 x n^2 puzzles have.